# InvalidDestination Exception in JMS

Tags: jms

I am getting the exception `javax.jms.invaliddestinationexception` while trying to send the message. Have configured all the queues in IBM websphere.

```
2018-10-29 20:43:37,968 [WebContainer : 0] DEBUG com.schawk.gcs.image.workflow.subsystem.request.ShotCreationRequest - Dispatching shot creation request for photo id 1350108
2018-10-29 20:43:37,969 [WebContainer : 0] DEBUG com.schawk.gcs.integration.AbstractDispatcherService - Error on ImageShotCreationIntegrationJmsDispatcher : CWSIA0062E: Failed to create a MessageProducer for queue://gcsToWHShotSyncQueue; nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: CWSIA0062E: Failed to create a MessageProducer for queue://gcsToWHShotSyncQueue; nested exception is com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.exceptions.SIMPNotPossibleInCurrentConfigurationException: CWSIK0015E: The destination gcsToWHShotSyncQueue was not found on messaging engine N4SRMGCS04LDNode01.server1-gcsBus.
com.schawk.gcs.integration.GcsIntegrationException: CWSIA0062E: Failed to create a MessageProducer for queue://gcsToWHShotSyncQueue; nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: CWSIA0062E: Failed to create a MessageProducer for queue://gcsToWHShotSyncQueue; nested exception is com.ibm.ws.sib.processor.exceptions.SIMPNotPossibleInCurrentConfigurationException: CWSIK0015E: The destination gcsToWHShotSyncQueue was not found on messaging engine N4SRMGCS04LDNode01.server1-gcsBus.
        at com.schawk.gcs.image.shot.creation.integration.ImageShotCreationIntegrationJmsDispatcher.doDispatch(ImageShotCreationIntegrationJmsDispatcher.java:60)
        at com.schawk.gcs.integration.AbstractDispatcherService.dispatchRequest(AbstractDispatcherService.java:22)
        at com.schawk.gcs.image.shot.creation.integration.AbstractImageShotCreationIntegrationDispatcher.dispatchRequest(AbstractImageShotCreationIntegrationDispatcher.java:19)
        at com.schawk.gcs.image.workflow.subsystem.request.ShotCreationRequest.executeRequest(ShotCreationRequest.java:48)
        at com.schawk.gcs.image.workflow.impl.ImageWorkFlowInitServiceImpl.startWorkflow(ImageWorkFlowInitServiceImpl.java:114)
        at com.schawk.gcs.workflow.service.web.controller.WorkflowController.workflowProcessFromJson(WorkflowController.java:129)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a tricky problem and from the error appears to be:

> The destination gcsToWHShotSyncQueue was not found on messaging engine

which appears to be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901043/does-anyone-know-exactly-what-javax-jms-invaliddestinationexception-not-allowed). In summary:

> This exception must be thrown when a destination either is not
>   understood by a provider or is no longer valid.

which appears to match the original error of the destination not found